# A Voynichian Challenge

Tags: language, symbols

Background: what follows is not a foreign language. Rather, it is a symbol-based code of English. You could think of it as falling between semaphore flags, which use a symbol per letter, and Shavian, which is based on English phonology.

[image]

Vague Hint:

> Each line translates to a line out of Daffodils, The Tyger, and A Psalm of Life

A slightly more complex piece of writing
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the huge vague hint, I think these are:

> I wandered lonely as a cloud
>  In the forests of the night
>  Life is but an empty dream

In the annotated picture below

> [image: annotated with circles]

The red circles are

> as, a, is, an

The blue circles are

> the L sound in LONELY, CLOUD, LIFE

The green circles are

> the T sound in FORESTS, NIGHT, BUT, EMPTY

The black circles are

> the AI diphthong in I, NIGHT, LIFE

The brown circles are

> the M sound in EMPTY and DREAM

Other cues:

> the N in NIGHT and IN is the same as the N in AN
>  the symbol for THE

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right as I came to the same conclusions but the "wandered" seems off, particularly the second half of the word is not as expected.

Comment: Also, the end of the word "lonely". Although "the" is represented by a single symbol so maybe the same is going on here?

Comment: Great job @shoover and @ hexomino you are correct. There's a decent bit of options here, with the original three lines mostly following a "symbol-per-letter" rule. I've edited the post to include a piece with a few more complex symbols. The original idea was to have a symbology that was both concise and variable. In other words, depending on the flow of writing, the same letter/phoneme/ending could be written in many ways. I may try to add a fuller example at a later time